# Uniqueness of $V\rightarrow \frac{DV}{dt}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

As picture below, although I have (1), I can't get the unique. Because
$$
\frac{DV_1}{dt}=\frac{dv_1^j}{dt} X_j  +\frac{dx_i}{dt}v_1^j\Gamma_{ij}^k X_k
=(\frac{dv_1^k}{dt}  +\frac{dx_i}{dt}v_1^j\Gamma_{ij}^k )X_k
$$
if $\frac{DV_1}{dt}=\frac{DV_2}{dt}$ , I have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(v_1^k-v_2^k)+\frac{dx_i}{dt}\Gamma_{ij}^k(v_1^j-v_2^j)=0
$$
But this don't mean $V_1=V_2$. Where is my mistake ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: You are confusing unique with injective.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus  Thanks, I get it .